# Generate SSL certificates to connect db to data studio

Tags: digital-ocean, looker-studio

I'm trying to connect my postgreSQL db from digitalocean to google datastudio. 
I've no expertise creating those SSL certificates you need to authorize Data studio get the DB.

What datastudio ask for:

-Server certificate
-Client certificate
-Client Private key

What I've managed to get from digital ocean:

-CA certificate.

What I supposed to do? Any ideas?
I've been really stacked for days trying to do this. Just want to get that connection.

I'd really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and followed the instructions for client certificate generation:

1. Generate a random number with OpenSSL (this avoids an error message saying 'Can't load ~/.rnd into RNG' during step 2)

   ```
   openssl rand -out .rnd
   ```
2. Generate the client certificate with OpenSSL

   ```
   openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout client-key.pem -out client-cert.pem -days 3650 -nodes -subj '/CN=localhost'
   ```
3. Upload the files you generated - `client-cert.pem` as client certificate and `client-key.pem` as client key in addition to your CA certificate

This process worked for me with a Amazon RDS DB using their provided CA certificate.

Comment: I found this also worked trying to connect data studio to a Postgres Server hosted with Aiven.io
(You grab the server certificate from the webconsole in Aiven)

Comment: Worked for me! I was confused because I thought the client certificate and key needed to be provided by Digital Ocean, but they do not.

Comment: @tom Are you able to connect to DigitalOcean Managed PostgreSQL from Data Studio? I  tried uploading the CA certificate provided together with generated client certificate and key but still can't connect. Note that DO only provide CA certificate not server certificate.